# Error: order.by requires an appropriate time-based object PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, time-series, xts

'sI am new to R and even more to ts objects. I try to use the package PerformanceAnalytics on a vector from a dataframe (df).

I have the following data frame:

```
    row.names   Date    PnL
1   22  1992-01-02  -1.751133e-02
2   23  1992-01-03  -1.586737e-02
3   24  1992-01-06  -2.898982e-02
```

I tried:

```
  TestS=SharpeRatio.annualized(df[,"PnL"],Rf=0,scale=252)
  TestS=SharpeRatio.annualized(as.ts(df[,"PnL"]),Rf=0,scale=252)
```

It returns respectively the error in the object and:

> Error in checkData(R, method = "xts") : 
>     The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'

```
dput(df[,"PnL")=0.00994504296273811, 0.00156467225423175, 0.00976137048829638, etc.
dputdf[,"Date")=8036, 8037, 8040, 8041,etc.
```

The package's help says the function works on vector. I don't have any NA, and therefore I don't see why it does not work.

Comment: That's not a very good use of `dput`. The purpose of `dput` is to share the data in a way that preserves things like the structure and attributes of the data, which may (as in this case) have an impact on how your data is handled. You can see from the error that your object is not an `xts` time series, which the function expects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to convert your data frame to an `xts` object:

```
dfx = xts(df$PnL, order.by=as.Date(df$Date))
```

Then you can do:

```
TestS = SharpeRatio.annualized(dfx, Rf=0, scale=252)
```

Or whatever else you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

PerformanceAnalytics attempts to convert your data into a form that is easier to work with internally.  To make this work with a `data.frame`, the `data.frame` has to have `rownames` that are formatted like `Date`s.  So, this would work

```
rownames(df) <- df[, 2]
(TestS=SharpeRatio.annualized(df[, "PnL", drop=FALSE], Rf=0, scale=252))
#                                      PnL
#Annualized Sharpe Ratio (Rf=0%) -8.767439
```

Although PerformanceAnalytics claims to work on many data types, the authors use `xts` extensively.  Therefore, they may have missed a few places where the code doesn't quite work right without using `xts`, such as passing a `vector` to this function.

I think the problem in `SharpeRatio.annualized` is that it calls `Return.excess` and `Return.excess` tries to turn your vector into an `xts` with this line

```
xR = coredata(as.xts(R) - as.xts(Rf))
```

However, a vector cannot be converted to `xts` without adding a time index. (Also, the next line uses `apply`, which isn't meant for vectors)